# How to load a .csv into a data table whilst avoiding any 65535 row limitations?

Tags: c#, csv, datatable, limit

I've got a very large spreadsheet I need to load into a datatable for processing.  From my understanding, datatables hold 16 million rows max, however when I load my csv in, I am getting 65535 which as we all know is a classic limitation.  My suspicions are that it's coming from the OLEDB Jet driver, but I have been looking everywhere and I can't seem to find a solution.

The only potential solution I ever found so far was to change the provider from Jet to ACE, but this did not fix the problem.

Here's the code:

```
OleDbDataAdapter dataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(string.Format("SELECT * FROM [{0}$]", sheetName), connectionString);

//OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OleDb.4.0; Data Source = " + Path.GetDirectoryName(FileName) + "; Extended Properties = \"Text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited\"");
OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = " + Path.GetDirectoryName(FileName) + "; Extended Properties = \"Text;HDR=YES;FMT=Delimited\"");
conn.Open();
OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM `" + Path.GetFileName(FileName) + "`", conn);

DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(myDataSet);
conn.Close();

DataTable dataTable = myDataSet.Tables[0];
```

I've tried both of these connection strings and the end result is always a datatable with 65535 rows when my spreadsheet has much more than that.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Update:

I've tried using LumenWorks as well (code below) but the ReadNextRecord() method always quits at 65534 (I am assuming the 1 row difference is the header).

So it seems somewhere I am hitting a limitation within the LumenWorks library as well.

```
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
dataTable.Reset(); 
FileStream logFileStream = new FileStream(FileName.ToString(), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);

using (CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(new StreamReader(logFileStream), true))
{
    int fieldCount = csv.FieldCount;

    string[] headers = csv.GetFieldHeaders();

    foreach (string strcolumn in headers)
    {
        dataTable.Columns.Add(strcolumn.ToLower());
    }

    while (csv.ReadNextRecord())
    {
        DataRow dtRow = dataTable.NewRow();

        for (int i = 0; i < fieldCount; i++)
        {
            dtRow[i] = csv[i];
        }

        dataTable.Rows.Add(dtRow);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you simply trying to import this into SQL server? If yes, you should look into SqlBulkCopy http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.aspx .. Loading that many rows into memory with a datatable just seems like a terrible idea to me

Comment: Nope, I am processing the data and writing the processed data back out to a different csv file.

Comment: Breakdown your data in chunks!

Comment: Or streamread that file. Loading it into memory all at once is just plain bad.

Answer (score 1):

you can give a try to [lumenworks](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader) library.

the library has been developed to handle CSV files several GB long that are not correctly handled by stock ODBC/OLEDB drivers so may fit your need also.
the author does not mention any limit about row number; may be worth to give it a try...

Comment: +1 for Lumenworks. I've successfully used this library to streamread an 8gb csv file.

Comment: I've actually got the library and used it before for other things.  For some reason I still seem to have the limitation.  Can you share the code you used to read the file with it?

Comment: Added the lumenworks code back in and ran through it.  when it hits the 65534th row, the ReadNextRecord() thinks it's done.  I'll check but I believe I'm using the latest version.

Comment: I'll Add my code that reads over 4 million records in a csv file that has 800 columns

Answer (score 0):

Using the Lumenworks CSV Reader library. This stream reads the file instead of loading the entire thing into memory at once.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using LumenWorks.Framework.IO.Csv;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading;

namespace TableBuilder
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            using (var fs = new FileStream("c:/Inbound/columns.csv", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(fs))
            {
                using (CsvReader csv = new CsvReader(sr, false))
                {
                    while (csv.ReadNextRecord())
                    {
                        //do processing with records here
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I've got very similar code (updated my original posting) and I still get the limitation.  I am not sure what you did that was different than what I am doing.

Comment: Do you have a properly formed CSV file? Is there anything on that row where it stops that is different from the other rows? An errant comma etc etc?